# When to_char's output in postgres is converted to Varchar, why is not comparing correctly with other varchars?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using to_char to get the day from the timestamp in postgres. On converting the result of that timestamp to varchar, because I want to apply some filters of type varchar, it doesn't give the correct result.

This query -

`select * from (SELECT  to_char(date (tableA.date), 'Day') AS day  from tableA) a ;`

gives weekdays in day column, which are days.

This query -

`select * from (SELECT pg_typeof( to_char(date (tableA.date), 'Day')) AS day  from tableA) a ;`

gives text in day column. because the type of it is "text".

And this final query gives 0 rows, it should give all the matching results.

`select * from (SELECT to_char(date (table.date), 'Day')::VARCHAR AS day  from table) a where day IN ('Thursday');`

Actual Output is 0 rows, Expected Output is 10 rows.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `varchar` instead of the normal `text`?

Comment: so that I can use the IN and NOT IN operators, for filtering out different varchars.@Bergi

Comment: But `'Thursday'` is text (by default) as well, it doesn't need to be `varchar`.

Comment: okay, can you provide some documentation where this is written, it's compatible both with text and varchar in postgres..

Comment: Yes, it's compatible with any textual type, but `text` is the preferred type in Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_char(date, 'Day')` returns a padded version of the day name, e.g. `'Thursday '` instead of `'Thursday'`.

If you want to remove the padding you can either use the FM modifier: `to_char(table.date, 'FMDay')` or trim: `trim(to_char(date, 'Day'))`

In general I would be very cautions about using locale specific comparisons e.g. on my computer this comparison would fail even if the padded spaces are removed, as it won't return `Thursday`. It's better to use numeric values, e.g. `extract(isodow from date) = 5`